# How to change from while to for loop

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp file which has the following code:

```
<% 
while(rs.next()){     //rs is the resultser

%>      
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';">
<td width="3%"><span style="font-size: 8pt"><%=i=i+1%></span></td>
<td width="10%"><span style="font-size: 8pt">
<a href="cir_view.jsp?cir_id=<%=rs.getString("cir_id")%>
```

and I want to change the while loop to a for loop. I tried this but, I was stuck trying to retrieve the values for the cir_id. Here is my code:

```
<% 
for(int j=1; j<=totalCols; j++) {
%>      
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF';">
<td width="3%"><span style="font-size: 8pt"><%=j=j+1%></span></td>
<td width="10%"><span style="font-size: 8pt">
<a href="cir_view.jsp?cir_id=<%=rs.getString("cir_id")%>" >>> Here is the change??
```

Can you please help to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
<% 
for(int j=1; j<=totalCols && rs.next(); j++) {
%>      
.....
<a href="cir_view.jsp?cir_id=<%=rs.getString("cir_id")%>"
```

You can keep rs.next() in the for loop itself

Comment: @maas Change to j's code to "<%=(j+1)%>" in the body of your loop, that could be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

rs.next() is missing

Change your for loop to:

```
for(int j=1; j<=totalCols; j++,rs.next()) {
```

it could also be declared as

```
for(int j=1;rs.next(); j++) {
```

Comment: where i should keep it?

and is there any modification must be done to rs.getString("cir_id")% at the end?

Comment: totalcols is variable which is declared to limit the displaying of the records, suppose 5
Should I remoce it?

Comment: I used this
for(int j=1; j<=totalCols && rs.next(); j++) { 
 and only the first record is displayed

Comment: @maas did you try my solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

[`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is meant to be iterated through in similar vein as [`Iterator`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) which means that you need to call `next()` to move the "cursor" to next record in `ResultSet`.